# Database/System design for multiple RPi and main server

Tags: database

I have a project where I am planning on using maybe 4 raspberry pis to record a bunch of different sensor info like temperature, humidity etc. I would like to be able to access this info from a webpage. For this, I am assuming it'll be easier from the website perspective to pull data from a single database that's hosted on the same server. So plan for that is to have the server host an SQL server to access the data.

For the raspberry pis, my plan is for them to record the sensor information and I would like the information to be recorded even if there's a connectivity issue with the main server. Therefore I assume the Pi's will require their own internal databases to write to. I am thinking of either SQL on each pi or something simpler like an sqlite file and pulling or pushing the data to the main database at a set interval of time.

I am not super experienced in this field, so am wondering if there is an obvious flaw in continuing with this method, or if there's an easier way that already exists I may not be aware of?

Comment: This is a very subjective question. I'm not sure there is a single correct answer. There is no authority that governs the design of systems like this. You will need to do your own independent analysis of the requirements and compare that to possible solutions. Consider creating a small proof of concept and try your purpose solution.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I will do just that.